# receiver syntax as pointer semantics

Tags: go

For the below data:

```
type Product struct {
    ID          int     `json:"id"`
    Name        string  `json:"name"`
}

var productList = []*Product{
    &Product{
        ID:          1,
        Name:        "Latte",

    }, &Product{
        ID:          2,
        Name:        "Espresso",
    },
}
```

---

Receiver semantics syntax(shown below) works fine using type definition:

```
package data

type Products []*Product

func (p *Products) ToJSON(w io.Writer) error {
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
    return encoder.Encode(p)
}
```

---

But below syntax gives error(`invalid receiver *[]*Product (basic or unnamed type)`):

```
package data


func (p *[]*Product) ToJSON(w io.Writer) error {
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
    return encoder.Encode(p)
}
```

---

[spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receiver) says: "Its type must be a defined type `T` or a pointer to a defined type `T`. `T` is called the receiver base type. A receiver base type cannot be a pointer or interface type"

and

[spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) also says: `Product` is a defined type, So my understanding is, `[]*Product` is also defined type.

---

Is `[]*Product` not a defined type? Why receiver syntax `(p *[]*Product)` not a valid syntax?

Comment: `Products` is a defined type, `[]*Product` is that defined type's underlying type, but is not itself a defined type.

Answer (score 3):

`[]*Product` is not a defined type. The language spec explicitly specifies the basic defined types, and as a type defined by:

```
type Name BaseType
```

Thus, `[]Type` is not a defined type. If:

```
type NewType []Type
```

Then `NewType` is a defined type.

Comment: Oh yes.. `[]*Product` is not a defined type.